# Convert String back into an array PHP

Tags: php

I have two different torrent scrapping classes and I want to combine them, they are working fine separately but the only problem is, when I convert my string into an array, it does not work.

That's the codes I am using so far.

```
<?php
require 'scraper.php';
require 'tor-info.php';

$scraper = new Scrapeer\Scraper();
$torrent = new Torrent( './test.torrent' );

$hashix = $torrent->hash_info();
var_dump($torrent->scrape()); // shows trackers list like this array(21) { ["udp://tracker4.piratux.com:6969/announce"]=> bool(false) ["udp://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce"]=> bool(false) ["udp://tracker.pomf.se:80/announce"]=> bool(false) ["udp://torrent.gresille.org:80/announce"]=> bool(false) so on..

$trackers = array( "udp://tracker4.piratux.com:6969/announce", "udp://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce", "udp://tracker.pomf.se:80/announce" ); // now here we need that trackers list
$hash = array( $hashix );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hash, $trackers );

//print_r( $info );

echo '<br><hr>';

foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
echo 'SEEDS :' .$value['seeders'].'<br />';
echo 'LEECHES :' .$value['leechers'].'<br />';
}

?>
```

In the first part I converted the array into String to get the readable result, and then in the second part I needed to convert that string back into single array to produce the result.

Comment: What does the recombining looks like?

Comment: I need to get recombining like this `$trackers = array ("udp://tracker4.piratux.com:6969/announce","udp://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce")`

Comment: It displays the result like this `array ( 0 => '"udp://tracker4.piratux.com:6969/announce"', 1 => '"udp://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce"', 2 => '"udp://tracker.pomf.se:80/announce"' )`

Comment: yes, its the expected result the only problem is the Converting string back into single array, after it is converted into string

Comment: I need those to work like this `$trackers = array($tracker);
 
 $hash = array($hashix);
 $info = $scraper->scrape( $hash, $trackers );`

Comment: you mean like this `$trackers=[implode(',',$tracker)];

 $trackers = array($trackers);` its not working either

Comment: no quote should not be removed in the single array, otherwise it won't work, in the first part I have converted the array into string, then I manage to put quotes around the string to make it work like array, but when I put that string into array like this `array($tracker);` it does not work, so where is the issue?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/medariox/Scrapeer ?

Comment: yes I am @apokryfos

Comment: yes I know that very well, and this is what I am doing already @mickmackusa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make them an array to begin with?

```
<?php
require 'scraper.php';
require 'tor-info.php';

$scraper = new Scrapeer\Scraper();
$torrent = new Torrent( './test.torrent' );    
$hashix = $torrent->hash_info();
$trackers = array_keys($torrent->scrape());

$hash = array( $hashix );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hash, $trackers );

echo '<br><hr>';

foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
   echo 'SEEDS :' .$value['seeders'].'<br />';
   echo 'LEECHES :' .$value['leechers'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: ok I have tried like this `$trackerArray = [];
foreach($torrent->scrape() as $trackx => $k) {
    $trackerArray[] = $trackx;
}
$tracker = '"'.implode('","',$trackerArray).'"';
$trackers = array($tracker);
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hash, $trackers );`
but still not working

Comment: @Aliza the point was to have the array since you needed it for `$scaper->scrape($hash, $trackersArray);` See the update.

Comment: Ok I have tried like this now `$trackerArray = array_keys($torrent->scrape());
 $tracker = '"'.implode('","',$trackerArray).'"';
 $trackers = array($tracker); 
 $hash = array('40e22987e52a8a90b2513792266905dae84cb29f');
 $info = $scraper->scrape( $hash, $trackers );` but still doesn't work

Comment: I don't think I can help you.

Comment: It works like this, `$trackers = array("udp://tracker4.piratux.com:6969/announce","udp://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce");
 
 $hash = array('40e22987e52a8a90b2513792266905dae84cb29f');
 $info = $scraper->scrape( $hash, $trackers );` but when we use that string into a single array, it does not work, and i need to convert that string into an array, because that string is dynamic

Comment: @Aliza My update 20+minutes ago suggested you try `scrape($hash,$trackerArray)` , have you done that at all?

Comment: yes it did work the first part @apokryfos now the hash part to fix it

Comment: @Aliza I've updated the code. I think it should be what you need.

Comment: I am using codes like this now `$hash = array_keys($torrent->hash_info());
$trackerArray = array_keys($torrent->scrape());
$info = $scraper->scrape($hash, $trackerArray);` the tracker part is working fine, now the only hash part is remaining.

Comment: You should **not** be doing `array_keys` on the `hash_info`.

Comment: Thanks to everybody its solved now, special thanks to @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

Since your string looks like this (from comment) : `"udp://tracker4.piratux.com:6969/announce","udp://tracker.trackerfix.com:80/announce"` you could use PHP's explode() function like so:

```
$recombined = explode(',', str_replace('"', '', $trackers));
```

Comment: thanks for your kind response, but if I don't use quotes around the string, it does not work in the array.